# Drupal 7 Breaks CSS Rule Ordering Standards when CSS Aggregation is Turned On

Tags: theming, performance, css-js-aggregation

Drupal 7 has an interesting bug (some may consider this a feature) when rules are included before an external CSS document is included using `@import`. The CSS Aggregation engine will let you "bend the rules" by declaring CSS before calling external stylesheets with `@import`. While there are very different solutions provided here, they both solve the issue.

**Example CSS:**

This example works with CSS Aggregation turned *ON* but will not work if CSS Aggregation is *OFF*.

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
@import 'header.css';
@import 'component-a.css';
@import 'component-b.css';
@import 'footer.css';
```

My assumption is that Drupal 7 CSS Aggregation engine actually fetches the contents of the `@import` calls and appends the contents to the main file as a subroutine.

---

**Solution:**

The solution was to follow the CSS standards by moving all of the `@import` calls to the top of the document, before declaring rules internally.

```
@import 'header.css';
@import 'component-a.css';
@import 'component-b.css';
@import 'footer.css';
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

While this question was originally marked as "off-topic", I think *it's still important to illustrate how CSS is interpreted by the Drupal 7 CSS Aggregation Engine*. It should be understood that these two different methods are VERY DIFFERENT in the way they are interpreted since CSS is sensitive to rule ordering.

---

**More Accurate Solution:**

The more accurate solution to this problem would be to include the first line in another CSS document, for instance `reset.css`.

```
@import 'reset.css';
@import 'header.css';
@import 'component-a.css';
@import 'component-b.css';
@import 'footer.css';
```

---

I hope this helps other people understand the nuances of the Drupal 7 CSS Aggregation engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own question. There were rules that came before the @import. So this wasn't a Drupal 7 issue, it was a CSS interpretation error.